# Using screen-scrape to pull back a table row where the data is a background

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to pull back data from a website that has multiple tables in a single page. Unfortunately, one of the columns, the most important one unfortunately, the field is what appears to be a box with a back-ground of what I need. I looked at the data in the source data and it does call the background what I need to pull back. My question is how can I make the data pull back the name of the background.

For example:
https://sc2replaystats.com/replay/playerStats/11014440/2585422

The build order table has a picture of a Hatchery, I would like to pull the data back where it is a text of "Hatchery" and the rest of the information regularly.

Comment: You can extract the `background-image` URL from the `style` attribute with a regular expression.

Comment: You can also get the `title="Hatchery"` attribute. Is that what you want?

Comment: Why are you doing screen scraping instead of web scraping?

Comment: please share your current code and explain what you mean by _and the rest of the information regularly_

Comment: I was hoping that if it were simple someone might be able to generate it for me. Not trying to be lazy, but this is the only python I need for this project and don't know python to push through this part. I've been manually entering the information generated on my tables